# .NET Core attribute routing with culture specified in url

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm redirecting application to default culture when is run so URL is `https://example.com/en`

In controller I'm trying to use attribute routing.

```
    public class ServicesController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("{culture?}/services/simple")]
        public IActionResult Simple()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("{culture?}/services/not-simple")]
        public IActionResult NotSimple()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

In view I tried to call with

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Services" asp-action="NotSimple">Not Simple</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("NotSimple")">Not Simple</a>
```

But it does not work, URL is generated as `https://example.com/en/services/notsimple`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution in view

```
@{
string currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
}

<a href="@Url.Action("NotSimple", "Services", new { culture = currentCulture })">Go to Not Simple</a>
```